# What does tilde mean in julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

What does tilde (`~`) mean in julia? For example here:

```
using DataFrames
dt=readtable("timelog 54660.csv", separator=';')
dt[~[(x in [:Date, :Topic, :Hours]) for x in names(dt)]]
```

I can't find revelant info in julia docs. Search for tilde or "~" seems to give nothing

Comment: Always open up the REPL and use the help which is available by default.

Comment: it's worth pointing out that something like `~[true, false, true]` will be deprecated in new julia versions in favour of `.~`, and also that the `.!` operator would probably have made more logical sense here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the help mode in the REPL by typing a question mark,

?~ gives the following output :

```
help?> ~
search: ~

  ~(x)

  Bitwise not.

  julia> ~4
  -5

  julia> ~10
  -11

  julia> ~true
  false
```